# Limit AOSP build RAM use?

Tags: android, build, android-source, ninja

I am trying to build the AOSP 12 and when I reach the soong_build process, ninja maxes out all my RAM and cpu cores. I am using an i7 6700k(8 threads) and 16gb of ram. I have tried `make -j1` and other values of `-j`, but still ninja ignores any of these values, I have tried using ZRam and/or increasing swap size and no luck. When resources max out my pc halts and terminal crashes w/o an error. So is there any way to limit the resources ninja uses ?

Comment: Have you seen: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-how-to-build-android-11-with-low-ram.4298483/

Comment: Yeah but still no luck, I can build any AOSP 11 product, but I can only build aosp_arm-eng from AOSP 12 and no other product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I upgraded to 32gb of ram and now it works fine.